# How to add a txt file in the terminal without putting any data in it

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint

I am trying to add a textfile to the desktop and then delete it, i did have the code working to create the file, but now whenever i create it, it then makes me put data into it, whatever i type in the terminal is saved into the created txt file. What i need is for the file to be created and then the user selects another option from the menu.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to perform some simple tasks
#
chmod 755 TaskB.sh
while:
do
clear
echo "*********************"
echo "* Tools *"
echo "*********************"
echo "* [1] Install gnome-disk-utility and gparted *"
echo "* [2] Create CET103Demo.txt *"
echo "* [3] Delete CET103Demo.txt *"
echo "* [4] Search BASH *"
echo "* [0] Exit/Stop *"
echo "*********************"
echo -n "Enter your menu choice [0-4]: "
read yourch
case $yourch in
1) *Not yet inserted code* ;;
2) cat > Desktop/CET103Demo.txt;;
3) rm Desktop/CET103Demo.txt;;
4) *Not yet inserted code* ;;
0) exit 0;;
*) echo "Oooops!!! Please select choice 1,2,3,4 or 0";
echo "Press Enter to continue..."; read ;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I understood you right, try to change

```
2) cat > Desktop/CET103Demo.txt;;
```

into

```
2) touch Desktop/CET103Demo.txt;;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a file, a portable way is to use this snippet :

```
:> Desktop/CET103Demo.txt
```

`:` stands for `true` (same command) : it's just a command that exit with a 0 status.
Redirected to a file, it will create the file. That works on most of the different Unix-like shells.

---

> $ LANG=C help :
>   :: :
>       Null command.
>
> ```
> No effect; the command does nothing.    
>
> Exit Status:    
> Always succeeds.
> ```

---

> $ LANG=C help true
>   true: true
>       Return a successful result.
>
> Exit Status:
>      Always succeeds.

---

> $ LANG=C help false false: false
>       Return an unsuccessful result.
>
> ```
> Exit Status:    
> Always fails.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options..

```
touch file.txt # preferred option
cat /dev/null > file.txt
true > file.txt
echo -n > file.txt
```